# How to Reach the Next Element in HTML

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having trouble with my code not printing all the strings that I want and I am unsure of how to edit my code to change that.

I am trying to scrape all the strings including things like *460 hp @ 7000 rpm* which it is currently not scraping. Ideally the strings in the *strong* elements are kept separate. I have tried adding another *.next_sibling*, changing the *br* to *p* and *strong* they just return an error.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="specs-content">
   <p>
     <strong>Displacement:</strong>
     " 307 cu in, 5038 "
     <br>
     <strong>Power:</strong> 
     " 460 hp @ 7000 rpm "
     <br>
     <strong>Torque:</strong>
     " 420 lb-ft @ 4600 rpm "
   </p>
   <p>
     <strong>TRANSMISSION:</strong> 
     " 10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode "
   </p>
   <p>
     <strong>CHASSIS</strong>
     <br>
     " Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink "
     <br>
     " Brakes (F/R): 15.0-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc "
     <br>
     " Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, F: 255/40ZR-19 (100Y) R: 275/40ZR-19 (105Y) "
   </p>
</div>
```

I have written the following code thus far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = requests.get('https://www.LinkeHere.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')

FindClass = soup.find(class_='specs-content')
FindElement = FindClass.find_all('br')

for Specs in FindElement:
    Specs = Specs.next_sibling
    print(Specs.string)
```

This returns:

---

Power:

Torque:

Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink

Brakes (F/R): 13.9-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc

Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, 255/40ZR-19 (100Y)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with adding a newline `\n` as the `separator` argument:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """THE ABOVE HTML SNIPPET"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="specs-content"):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").replace('"', ""))
```

Output:

```
Displacement:
 307 cu in, 5038 
Power:
 460 hp @ 7000 rpm 
Torque:
 420 lb-ft @ 4600 rpm 
TRANSMISSION:
 10-speed automatic with manual shifting mode 
CHASSIS
 Suspension (F/R): struts/multilink 
 Brakes (F/R): 15.0-in vented disc/13.0-in vented disc 
 Tires: Michelin Pilot Sport 4S, F: 255/40ZR-19 (100Y) R: 275/40ZR-19 (105Y)
```

Comment: Please tell me what the separator="\n" function does and why we need the replace('"', ""). I understand the the strip =True is striping the text of spaces on and the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @mewspoon 1. `separator="\n"` separates the tags with a new line. (see what happens when removing it, + see the link the docs).  2.  ` replace('"', "")` removes the quotation marks `"` from the string